# How to check if .ASPXAUTH cookie exists with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, .aspxauth

I have a strange problem. I want to check if .ASPXAUTH cookie exists with javascript. I do it like this:

```
authx = document.cookie.indexOf(".ASPXAUTH" + "=");
```

and the 'authx' value is always -1. But if I tray to find some other cookie like:

```
foo = document.cookie.indexOf("bar" + "=");
```

it works. Is there some restriction between javascript and .ASPXAUTH cookie???

Comment: well, the first question would be : did you check that the cookie is there ? did you check with firecookie or something, to make sure the cookie is there ?

Comment: Yes, i checked. Cookie is 100% there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was, that I had set the

```
HttpOnly = true;
```

which prevents the javascript accessing the cookie. I just set it to false and it works.

Comment: And of course it's meant to be HTTP only in order to avoid the risk of an XSS flaw grabbing your cookie and allowing your session to be hijacked. You've now opened up a vulnerability in your app.

Comment: Where did you set that? JS ?

Comment: @d.popov Obviously no!, You can set that in your web.config or (in asp.net mvc) as an attribute for each action method

Comment: @DrTJ - maybe for you, but not so obvious for someone reading the question. Neither the question, tags or the answer suggests so. The question even suggests JavaScript context!